# outlook plugin to catch compose mail events

Tags: c#, events, outlook, vsto, email

I got an adjoining formregion in the compose mail form and i dont find the way to intercepts the form events like the drag and dropping of a file inside the message or the insertion of a text.

NB: Ms has forbidden the complete replacement of the compose mail form so i cannot re-write the form has i want

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Outlook Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/). It makes magics...

Answer (score 0):

[Add-In Express](http://www.add-in-express.com/outlook-extension/) might help.